# Shrink ClipRect to its content

Tags: dart, flutter

I use a `ClipRect` to only show a part of a widget, but I need it to shrink to its content.

Is there any way to do that?

```
class ClipExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ClipRect(
        clipper: MyClipper(),
        child: Image.asset('test.jpg'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect>{
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(100, 250, 150, 100);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

Comment: Could you add an image about what you want?

Comment: Yeap, can you add an image of what you want.

Comment: @diegoveloper It gives me this: https://imgur.com/Z19jIrF but I want it to be like this: https://imgur.com/FQNjtv6 (with a BoxFit.fitWidth).

Comment: @Hosar It gives me this: https://imgur.com/Z19jIrF but I want it to be like this: https://imgur.com/FQNjtv6 (with a container parent)